# Classic ASP Session not working in IIS 7 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64

Tags: session, iis-7, asp-classic, iis-6, session-variables

I've been googleing and searching here info about this but so far couldn't find anything relevant to my problem.

We have a website currently working on II6 and Windows Server 2003 (x86) without any problem. Now we want to migrate our server to a Virtual Machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64) and IIS7.

Out current app is built in Classic ASP and SQL Server (This one located on a 2nd Server but this is staying the way it is now).

The website is configured as a WebSite, not a virtual directory. Using DefaultAppPool with 4 applications.

Now, the problem I'm getting is with the Sessions, or at least that's what I think since I created a simple hello.asp with this code

```
<% 
response.write "Hello"
response.write Session.SessionID
%>
```

And this is giving us this result:

```
Hello error '8002801d' 
/hello.asp, line 3
```

ASP Sessions Properties

```
Enable Session State : True
Maximum Sessions : 2147483647
New ID On Secure Connection : True
Time-out : 20 min
```

This is the log in Event Viewer

Warning 24/12/2010 14:03:42 Active Server Pages 9 None

FailedReqLog

> Url
>   http://apps.shocklogic.com:80/hello.asp
>   App Pool DefaultAppPool 
>   Authentication anonymous  User from
>   token NT AUTHORITY\IUSR  Activity ID
>   {00000000-0000-0000-1400-0080000000F8}
>   Site 1  Process 3312  Failure Reason
>   STATUS_CODE  Trigger Status 500  Final
>   Status 500  Time Taken 110 msec

Would be great if anyone has any ideas.

Thanks,
Federico

Comment: Have you installed support for ASP in the IIS7 ?

Comment: Yes done it from scratch

Comment: Does this message ever appear in the error: "Library Not Registered"

Comment: No, but that's what I read on the internet about this error 8002801d meaning ASP library not registered but have no idea how to register it in server 2008

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like ASP is a bit clobbered. Try uninstalling then re-installing. You can do this from PowerShell with minimal faffing about:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-ASP
Add-WindowsFeature Web-ASP
```

Have you tried to run the application pool in 32-bit mode?

Comment: @user - hmm....that's not good. I hate suggesting this, but did you try a server reboot?

Comment: @user - do any of the other ASP intrinsics work - Request.QueryString() etc?

Comment: @user - Have you tried to run the application pool in 32-bit mode?

Comment: I just tried different asp commands and the only one that is working is Response.Write. And I googled this error 8002801d and I found that might be ASP.DLL not registered or a permission issue but can't figure out how to check if it is registered in WS 2008 x64 or where do I need to apply the permissions. If by 32bit mode you mean the setting Enable 32bit application then yes I tried it already.